# MS Access 2010 SQL Query Syntax Error due to comma in field

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I've been having issues with this code I've written to update a field (txtUOM) in MS Access 2010.

```
Private Sub cboSelector_Change()

  Dim myItemCode As String
  Dim QfindUOM As String

  myItemCode = Me.cboSelector.Column(0)
  QfindUOM = ("SELECT item_details.uom from item_details 
              where item_details.itemCode=" & myItemCode & " end")

  DoCmd.RunSQL (QfindUOM)

End Sub
```

At this point, I haven't gotten around to actually updating txtUOM since the SQL won't even run.  The syntax error hits me,because myItemCode has commas inside (i.e. 822,60 or 6,01) and I can't get rid of this because the database I've been asked to work with has this as the 'item numbers' of the inventory. Any suggestions on how I might be able to manage this?  I've tried adding parenthesis and apostrophes but they don't seem to help. For example, in the case of item 6,09:

```
Run-time error '3075': 
Syntax error (comma) in query expression 'item_details.itemCode=6,09 end'.
```

There are also some items with itemCodes that don't have commas inside (i.e. 6909), and the error I get is as follows:

```
Run-time error '3075':
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'item_details.itemCode=6909 end'.
```

I'm guessing there's something going terribly wrong in my code and would really appreciate any suggestions you can give!

Thanks for taking the time to read this question!

Comment: what's the datatype of the field 'itemCode'?

Comment: A couple of things look odd about this to me: first, get rid of `END` at the end if the query. Second, you don't need the brackets after `DoCmd.RunSql`. Thirdly, the SQL that you run is a `SELECT` and so has no side-effects (it doesn't *do* anything!)

Comment: @Paolo the datatype is "Text"

@LondonRob when I remove `end` I get the error Run-time error '2342': A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement; and I'm still trying to figure out how to get it to update the textbox contents (I'm working along the lines of using `txtUOM.value = *result of SQL here*` but before that I'm guessing I need to sort out my SQL first.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add single quotes:

```
 QfindUOM = ("SELECT item_details.uom from item_details 
          where item_details.itemCode='" & myItemCode & "' end")
```

or Double, I forget with access:

```
 QfindUOM = ("SELECT item_details.uom from item_details 
          where item_details.itemCode=""" & myItemCode & """ end")
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony! It's gotten rid of the comma error with the double quotes now so only the "missing operator" error is left. I can't imagine which operator is missing though.

Comment: What's the "end" for?  Normally a SQL thing.  Is it needed?

Comment: If I don't put out the "end" Microsoft VBA gives me Run-time error '2342': A RunSQL action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement.

I guess that means it's necessary for Access, at least.

Comment: Just seems that as per TechNet, it is not required.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220717(v=office.11).aspx